# How to remotely test the linux install CD for integrity

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

if you do, after the completing the test - it will eject the CD.

and how are you going to reinsert the CD to complete your install? you're remote remember ??

Comment: The BIOS should close the CdROM tray on start. But this is not the place to ask this question.

Comment: How to do that, can you please help me out.

Comment: I guess the right place to ask would be: http://serverfault.com. Talking about the question, you should provide more details (which installation cd of which distro, how do you connect, etc.). If you need to close the cd tray from a Linux shell, the command is `eject -t`. But I suggest using `md5sum` to check the cd before attempting to use it, since the cd checking mechanism could be potentially broken too, faking the test results..

Comment: @leppie: Is there any guarantee that a reboot will actually make BIOS close the CD tray, or is it just a usual by-product of POST?

Comment: @leppie What if the drive uses a slot, rather than a tray?

Answer (score 1):

As leppie says, a reboot should also fix this. Unless it's a laptop or slot style CD drive, it should be closed during POST.

Answer (score 0):

redShadow's answer +1

`eject -t`  to close the tray, but the `md5sum` is the better method. You can get the md5 key from the distro site.